# Modifying the equation number with simple calculation

Tags: numbering, calculations

I am trying to modify the equation numbering as follows

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{FFF(\arabic{SomeCounter}).\arabic{equation}},
```

where SomeCounter is a counter defined as `\newcounter{SomeCounter}` and `FFF(x)` is a simple arithmetic function.  Specifically, `FFF(x) = 2 * x+1`.

I know there are several packages such as `calc` and `calculator` but I could not find a way to use them in this context. Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeX has limited arithmetic capabilities; in this simple case you can say

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{%
   \the\numexpr 2*\value{SomeCounter}+1\relax.\arabic{equation}%
}
```

More complex functions could be used, with more complex methods.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for.